# How do you join a custom table to a node from a field with hook_views_data()

Tags: 8, views

I have a custom table that contains (for simplicity) two fields:

- id
- client_id

On my node content type, I have an integer type field called: field_dashboard_id.  All my nodes have the field_dashboard_id set to ids from the custom table.  I have a content view that I would like to also display the client id from the custom table. (FYI I am able to create a view if I use Dashboard Entries instead of Content but I want to use Content and join to Dashboard Entries)

I tried the following code but when I try to add a relationship, I am not seeing my custom table in Views.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_data().
 */
function mydashboard_views_data() {
  $data = [];

  $data['mydashboard_site']['table']['group'] = t('Dashboard');

  $data['mydashboard_site']['table']['base'] = [
    'field' => 'id',
    'title' => t('Dashboard entries'),
    'help' => t('Contains a list of dashboard entries.'),
  ];

  $data['mydashboard_site']['table']['join'] = array(
    'node' => array(
      'left_table' => 'node__field_dashboard_id',
      'left_field' => 'entity_id',
      'field' => 'id',
    ),
  );

  $data['mydashboard_site']['id'] = [
    'title' => t('ID'),
    'help' => t('Unique Site ID.'),
    'field' => [
      'id' => 'numeric',
    ],
    'filter' => [
      'id' => 'numeric',
    ],
    'argument' => [
      'id' => 'numeric',
    ],
    'sort' => [
      'id' => 'standard',
    ],
    'relationship' => [
      'base' => 'node', // The name of the table to join with.
      'base field' => 'field_dashboard_id', // The name of the field on the joined table.
      // 'field' => 'nid' -- see hook_views_data_alter(); not needed here.
      'handler' => 'views_handler_relationship',
      'label' => t('Default label for the relationship'),
      'title' => t('Title shown when adding the relationship'),
      'help' => t('More information on this relationship'),
      'extra' => [
        [
          'field'    => 'field_dashboard_id',
          'value'    => 'value',
          'operator' => '=',
          'numeric'  => true,
        ],
      ],
    ],
  ];

  $data['mydashboard_site']['client_id'] = [
    'title' => t('Client ID'),
    'help' => t('The client id'),
    'field' => [
      'id' => 'standard',
    ],
    'filter' => [
      'id' => 'string',
    ],
    'argument' => [
      'id' => 'string',
    ],
  ];

  return $data;
}
```

**Update**

Also tried the following:

```
$data['mydashboard_site']['table']['join'] = [
  'node__field_dashboard_id' => [
    'left_field' => 'field_dashboard_id_value',
    'field' => 'id',
  ],
];

'relationship' => [
  'base' => 'node__field_dashboard_id', // The name of the table to join with.
  'base field' => 'entity_id', // The name of the field on the joined table.
   // ID of relationship handler plugin to use.
  'id' => 'standard',
   // Default label for relationship in the UI.
  'label' => t('Example node'),
],
```

Comment: just a suggestion you could use hook_views_query_alter() to add your table in a condition group.
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/8.2.x

Comment: In the past, I used query alter for altering the query but never to add fields. Do you know how I would be able to add a field?

Comment: posted an answer because this would be to long to comment.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a field you have a table for it with stored values, so you just add the fields table to your query 
Like

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_query_alter().
 */
function HOOK_views_query_alter(ViewExecutable $view, QueryPluginBase $query) {  
   $query->addTable('my_fields_table');
   $query->addWhere(<condition group id>, '<table_column>', <value>, '<operator>');
   // These you can use to alter the behaviour for your condition group.
   //$query->setWhereGroup('OR/AND', <condition group id>);
   // This one is for the global group behavior.
   //$query->setGroupOperator('<OR/AND>');
  }
}
```